# Random sampling of non-adjacent cells in a pixel grid

Tags: python, numpy, random

Suppose that we have a `n*n` grid. We would like to choose `k << n` random cells of this grid which are not adjacent. If we simulate this grid with a 2D Numpy array containing `0` and `1`, what is the most efficient way to do this in Numpy/Python?

**Valid Example:**

[image]

**Non-valid Example:**

[image]

Comment: What distribution do you want to draw from? Do you want a uniform sample from the space consisting of all k-tuples-of-non-adjacent-pixels, because these kinds of combinatorial sampling problems can be extremely hard (e.g. sampling matrices with fixed row and column sums) even if they seem easy at first blush.

Comment: @Mr.F I am looking for uniform samples. I am not looking for all k-tuples. Just one k-tuple of non-adjacent-pixels are fine.

Comment: If the cells are really sparse in your grid then I would just do rejection sampling. Generate some candidate points by sampling uniformly, then check if any of them are adjacent, repeat until you find a valid set of points. You can do this check on the sparse data (i.e. the point coordinates) rather than checking the full n*n grid.

Comment: But it's the *space* of *all* such k-tuples that you have to describe when you want to make the draw (although in this case it seems likely that sequentially sampling one pixel at a time, then blanking out its boundary, might work to produce uniform k-tuples in the end).

Comment: I was thinking about this sequential sampling as well. That was my first option. Meanwhile, I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a straightforward implementation of the rejection sampling. There may be a faster way to do the adjacency check than the `query_pairs` thing (which in this case also will check for collisions), since you only want to test if there is at least one pair within this distance threshold.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as kdtree

n = 100
k = 50

valid = False

while not valid:
    # generate k grid indices
    coords_flat = np.random.random_integers(0, n ** 2 - 1, size=k)
    coords = np.unravel_index(coords_flat, dims=(n, n))
    # test there are no adjacent cells
    transposed = np.transpose(coords)
    valid = len(kdtree(transposed).query_pairs(1.0)) == 0

print(coords)
```

Taking a look at the results:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
grid = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=np.bool)
grid[coords] = True
plt.imshow(grid)
plt.savefig('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Your rejection sampling algorithm does not seem to be working. I think possibly `valid = len(kdtree(coords).query_pairs(1.0)) == 0` does not do what it's meant to here. Try `query_pairs(10)` or for some other number that is larger than 1...you'd see it does not produce the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The problem was that the data should have been transposed: `kdtree` was treating the input as two 50-dimensional data points. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

I saw, that it was an accepted answer already, but it was a challenging task, so I solved as follows and I enjoy it, thus I gave an **upvote** to the question :):

```
import numpy as np

xy = []

x = np.random.randint(0,5)
y = np.random.randint(0,5)

xy.append((x,y))

while True:

    x = np.random.randint(0,5)
    y = np.random.randint(0,5)

    for ii,i in enumerate(xy):    
        if x in [i[0]-1, i[0], i[0]+1]:
            if x == i[0]:
                if y in [i[1]-1, i[1], i[1]+1]:
                    break    
                else:
                    if ii == len(xy) - 1:
                        xy.append((x,y))
                        break
            elif y == i[1]:
                break
        elif ii == len(xy) - 1:
            xy.append((x,y))
            break

    if len(xy) == 3:
        break

for cords in xy:
    print cords

sq =np.zeros((5,5))

for cords in xy:
    sq[cords] = 1

print sq
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 0)
(4, 4)
(4, 1)
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

It always provides a random combination of non-adjacent cells.
Enjoy it! :)